# How use Regex in Localization Laravel 5.4 with Vue JS

Tags: php, regex, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to create SPA website with Laravel and Vue. I want to make localization too. But localization builds just use laravel without Vue. If I used regex to remove # in url (blog.com/#/) like this `web.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'locale'], function() {

   Route::get('/{vue?}', function() {
     return view('main');
   })->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
});

Route::get('lang/{locale}', function($locale) {
   Session::put('locale', $locale);
   return back();
 });
```

it worked.. but unfortunately this broke my localization url:

```
<li><a href="{{url('lang/id')}}"><img src="{{asset('images/flag/id.png')}}"></a></li>
<li><a href="{{url('lang/en')}}"><img src="{{asset('images/flag/en.png')}}"></a></li>
```

But if I deleted where from that route

```
 Route::get('/{vue?}', function() {
 return view('main');
})->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

Become like this:

```
 Route::get('/{vue?}', function() {
 return view('main');
});
```

It worked for the localization, but it doesn't work for some url, e.g:
http://blog.com/post/create

but If I change the url to http://blog.com/create, it worked..

**url test:**

**working:**

1. blog.com
2. blog.com/about
3. blog.com/create

**not working**

1. blog.com/posts/create

This is the vue routes `routes.js`

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
let routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    component: require('./pages/Home')
},
 {
    path: '/about',
    component: require('./pages/About')
},
{
    path: '/posts/create',
    component: require('./posts/create')
}
]

export default new VueRouter({
   routes,
   linkActiveClass: 'is-active',
   mode: 'history'

})
```

Comment: What if you put `path: '/create'`, and leave `component: require('./posts/create')` as is?

Comment: Your suggestion actually worked. But I just want to make the url become like this :  blog.com/posts/create. If I remove where from the route it (blog.com/posts/create) didn't worked. If I could choose, I just want to use regex to make the url `{{url('lang/id')}}` work for localization.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "didn't work" (I can't really see what it did), so maybe elaborate on that.

Comment: If I didn't use regex in my route (web.php) in laravel, it makes the route in vue routes.js didn't work for `/posts/create` but  worked for localization url `{{url('lang/id')}}`. If I use regex in my route (web.php), it broke the localization url `{{url('lang/id')}}` or can't translate the page but it worked well for `/posts/create`. I know that it's so confused.

Comment: You could possibly use a redirect for that one; so maybe path: '/create' and redirect: '/posts/create'. other than rethinking your regex that's all I can suggest for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solve now. I just use this code to solve this problem.

```
if ( ! request()->ajax() ) {
Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts'], function () {
    Route::get('/{vue?}', function() {
      return view('main');
    })->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
   });
 }
```